# JMeter shows result but the result is not visible in log (Debug)

Tags: jmeter

I just finished a test case in JMeter and the result is fine; however, I somehow want to see the result reflecting also in the log view.

For some reason, the Sample time (ms) is not reflecting on the log view (Log level: Debug)

Does someone have an idea on how to display that too?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add listeners to your test plan. Aggregate report and Tree view result, for example.
But use them only for debugging your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JMeter will report response times in the log file even given you set the most verbose logging level, if you want to have this data in log - I would recommend going for [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) instead.

1. Add JSR223 Listener to your test plan at the same level as all your Samplers live (or according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) if you want limited samplers to be affected)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   log.info(prev.getSampleLabel(true) + ' response time: ' + prev.getTime())
   ```
3. That's it, now you will be able to see the response times in the [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)

   [image]